# SQL Script for JIRA - How to Include Both User Login Counts And Non-Logged In Accounts

Tags: sql, jira

I'm trying to write a SQL query that tracks account usage in JIRA.  I'm still pretty novice when it comes to SQL so please bear with me :)

I'm able to obtain the login counts for users who have logged in. however, I'm not having much luck including the accounts that have never been used.

Below is an example of the **cwd_user_attributes table** - this is the table that contains the login counts, date last logged in, etc.  Once a user logs in, **"login.count"** will appear under the **attribute_name** column.  However, if a user has never logged in, such as user_id *19313 (AKA user Dave)*, **'login.count'** does not exist.

```
+-------+---------+-------------------------------+-----------------+
|  ID   | user_id |        attribute_name         | attribute_value |
+-------+---------+-------------------------------+-----------------+
| 17378 |   10000 | lastAuthenticated             | 1524069213477   |
| 17382 |   10000 | login.count                   | 2576            |
| 17380 |   10000 | login.lastLoginMillis         | 1524069213493   |
| 17377 |   10000 | requiresPasswordChange        | FALSE           |
| 23542 |   16714 | lastAuthenticated             | 1525888024307   |
| 23549 |   16714 | login.count                   | 1927            |
| 23548 |   16714 | login.lastLoginMillis         | 1525888024322   |
| 23537 |   16714 | requiresPasswordChange        | FALSE           |
| 27555 |   19313 | password.reset.request.expiry | 1494599702231   |
| 27554 |   19313 | passwordLastChanged           | 1494513302168   |
| 27552 |   19313 | requiresPasswordChange        | FALSE           |
+-------+---------+-------------------------------+-----------------+
```

I'm trying to write a query that will return the attribute_value when the **'login.count'** row is present in the **attribute_name** column AND will also return a result of **'0'** if there is no **'login.count'** row.

This is what I have so far.  Unfortunately, and understandably, this doesn't include my 19313/Dave user.

```
SELECT 
    u.user_name AS [USER NAME]
    ,m.parent_name AS [GROUP]
    ,ua.attribute_value AS [LOGIN COUNT]
    ,u.updated_date AS [LAST LOGIN]
    ,u.created_date AS [CREATED]
FROM     jira.cwd_user AS u LEFT JOIN
                  jira.cwd_user_attributes AS ua ON u.ID = ua.user_id LEFT JOIN
                  jira.cwd_membership AS m ON u.ID = m.child_id AND u.directory_id = m.directory_id LEFT JOIN
                  jira.cwd_directory AS d ON m.directory_id = d.ID
WHERE  (d.active = '1') AND (u.active = '1') AND (m.parent_name <> 'non-jira-users') AND (ua.attribute_name = 'login.count')
```

**RESULTS**

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| USER NAME | LOGIN COUNT |       LAST LOGIN        |         CREATED         |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Mark      |        2576 | 2012-09-26 17:06:11.400 | 2012-09-26 17:06:11.400 |
| Joe       |        1927 | 2016-06-21 11:41:03.897 | 2016-04-19 13:31:21.847 |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

After doing a ton of research, I thought a **"WHEN EXISTS"** clause would be my best bet.  And, if I remove the ***"(ua.attribute_name = 'login.count')"** from the WHERE clause, it returns all the users (yay!), but it also returns all of the attribute_names as well. And obviously, this doesn't create a "login.count" row...

```
SELECT 
    u.user_name AS [USER NAME]
    ,m.parent_name AS [GROUP]
    ,CASE
            WHEN EXISTS
                (SELECT ua.attribute_value
                WHERE ua.attribute_name = 'login.count')
                THEN ua.attribute_value
                ELSE 0
        END AS [LOGIN COUNT]
    ,u.updated_date AS [LAST LOGIN]
    ,u.created_date AS [CREATED]
FROM     jira.cwd_user AS u LEFT JOIN
                  jira.cwd_user_attributes AS ua ON u.ID = ua.user_id LEFT JOIN
                  jira.cwd_membership AS m ON u.ID = m.child_id AND u.directory_id = m.directory_id LEFT JOIN
                  jira.cwd_directory AS d ON m.directory_id = d.ID
WHERE  (d.active = '1') AND (u.active = '1') AND (m.parent_name <> 'non-jira-users')
```

**RESULTS**

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| USER NAME | LOGIN COUNT | LAST LOGIN |  CREATED  |
+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| Mark      |           0 | 9/26/2012  | 9/26/2012 |
| Mark      |           0 | 9/26/2012  | 9/26/2012 |
| Mark      |        2576 | 2/14/2019  | 9/26/2012 |
| Mark      |           0 | 9/26/2012  | 9/26/2012 |
| Joe       |        1927 | 2/14/2019  | 4/19/2016 |
| Joe       |           0 | 6/21/2016  | 4/19/2016 |
| Joe       |           0 | 6/21/2016  | 4/19/2016 |
| Joe       |           0 | 6/21/2016  | 4/19/2016 |
| Dave      |           0 | 5/11/2017  | 5/11/2017 |
| Dave      |           0 | 5/11/2017  | 5/11/2017 |
| Dave      |           0 | 5/11/2017  | 5/11/2017 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

**I'm trying to reach an end goal of:**

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| USER NAME | LOGIN COUNT | LAST LOGIN |  CREATED  |
+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| Mark      |        2576 | 9/26/12    | 9/26/12   |
| Joe       |        1927 | 6/21/16    | 4/19/16   |
| Dave      |           0 | NULL       | 5/11/2017 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

Apologies for the novel - tried to include as much pertinent info as possible :)  Thank you in advance!

**EDITED 2/15/19**
After reading Chuck's reply, I am trying his suggestion.  I am not there yet, but am I at least on the right track?  Apologies - this is all new to me.

Thank you!

```
SELECT
    u.user_name AS [USER NAME]
    ,ua.attribute_value AS [LOGIN COUNT]
    ,u.updated_date AS [LAST LOGIN]
    ,u.created_date AS [CREATED]
FROM    dbo.cwd_user AS u LEFT JOIN
        dbo.cwd_user_attributes AS ua ON u.ID = ua.user_id

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT 
    ,CASE
        WHEN EXISTS
            (
                SELECT ua1.attribute_value
                WHERE ua1.attribute_name = 'login.count'
            )
            THEN ua1.attribute_value
        ELSE 0
        END AS [LOGIN COUNT]
FROM    dbo.cwd_user AS u1 LEFT JOIN
        dbo.cwd_user_attributes AS ua1 ON u1.ID = ua1.user_id
) AS sq

ON ua.attribute_value = sq.attribute_value
WHERE (u.active = '1') AND (ua.attribute_name = 'login.count')
```

Comment: That is because you are referencing ua.attribute_name = 'login.count' in the where clause, this is causing your left join to not work as intended. Try doing a sub query of only the 'login.count' and then join to jira.cwd_user table.